# just need simple method to insert fetch bootstrap dropdown value with input text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I just need simple method to insert fetch bootstrap drop down value with input text but showing NAN
Scratching my head from a day not reaching any conclusion
so if any value is selected and input text filled it should give output on same page then upon save should enter value so that it can be fetched for printing receipts.  but showing NAN.Hope i get answer her as really strucked.Kindly overlook my poor English..

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="specs" class="control-label">Spec</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="specs" name="specs">
      <option selected>select</option>
      <option value="kt">Kt</option>
      <option value="ct">Ct</option>
      <option value="oth">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="0" name="specsa" class="form-control text-left" placeholder="specification">
</div>
```

```js
//Just for reference
specs = $('#specs').val();
specs = $obj.specs;
td.text(parseFloat(specs).toLocaleString('en-US'))
td.append("<input type='hidden' name='specs[]'    value='" + specs + "' />") //item  input
```

Comment: Why do you think `specs` will contain a float? Clearly the values in the options  are text. Do you understand that a float is a type of number?

Comment: i am learning.kindly let me know what value should i put

Comment: _str doesnt work

Comment: It's showing NaN because `parseFloat` requires a number and "kt" is not a number.    I suggest you need simply: `td.text(specs)` .

Comment: Alternatively, change your specs dropdown options, eg `<option value="1">Kt</option>`  it's unclear what kt/ct mean nor what this is called "Specs" (specification? spectacles?)   No doubt it's obvious on your page, but the snippet doesn't make this clear.

Comment: I don't know what you think `$obj.specs;` is for either? And `toLocaleString` also makes no sense because you can only call that on a Date or a Number, and as mentioned, you're not using either of those in your dropdown.

Comment: I think you can simplify the JS to just: `specs = $('#specs').val();
td.text(specs);
td.append("<input type='hidden' name='specs[]'    value='" + specs + "' />");`

Comment: P.S. Your problem has nothing to do with PHP or CSS or bootstrap. Its just an issue with plain HTML, JavaScript and jQuery. Don't tag stuff which is totally irrelevant to the specific issue, if you can help it.

Comment: Applaud.Genius people  judging by bare skeletons.Great.. @freedomn-m kt=karet for gold and ct caret for diamond spec specification  i will check and update but text is still showing Nan.

Comment: @Akrutitech Did you try my suggestion? It should not be possible for it to display NaN anymore with that code.

Comment: In fact, here's a demo which proves it: https://jsfiddle.net/p6s7m50t/

Comment: @ADyson removed off-topic chit-chat.  (yes it should be a meta, but probably won't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated it. The specific reason why you're seeing `NaN` (i.e. "Not A Number") is because the values in your options aren't numbers, so you cannot use `parseFloat()` to parse them.

This code is sufficient to read the value:

```
specs = $('#specs').val();
td.text(specs);
td.append("<input type='hidden' name='specs[]' value='" + specs + "' />");
```